# Adding Real Time firebase data to a flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

When i send data from my app to my firebase database, it works perfectly. I want to take this data and display it in a flatlist. I tried the way described below, but it wont show me anything in the flatlist. How would i be able to solve this problem?

Code for fetching data

```
 const [array,setArray] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
      firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) =>{
        var update = []
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
         update.push({
          key: child.key,
          posts:child.val().posts
        })
      })

    setArray({array:update}) .// i want to add the array "Update" to the array hook i initialized 
    })
   }, []);
```

code for my flatlist

```
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container1}>
 <FlatList
  data={array}
  keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}
  refreshing={refreshing} 
  onRefresh={onRefresh}
  renderItem={({item}) => ( 
  <TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.postText}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details',{newPost: item})}
  > 
   <Text style={styles.item}>{item.posts}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 )}
 
 />

    </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

**ISSUE**

Remove `{}` from below code

```
setArray({array:update})
```

**SOLUTION**

```
setArray(update);
```